# ¿Qué información muestra el comando ls -ld?

Tags: linux

Buscando un comando que me mostrara los usuarios que tienen permisos sobre ciertos directorios encontre este `ls -ld` y ciertamente me muestra la informacion, pero no me queda muy clara la estructura de la informacion que me muestra:

```
[root@test ws]# ls -ld
drwxrwxr-x 2 usertest usertest 4096 jul 14 03:10 .
```

El hecho de que salga dos veces el mismo usuario quiere decir que esta asignado dos veces?, en general quisiera una liga o si alguien puede poner algo mejor explicado, porque vi la ayuda del comando y no me dejo claro el sufijo `-ld`

Comment: El primer usuario es propietario y el segundo el grupo.

Comment: Gracias!, sabes a que se refiere la primera parte `drwxrwxr-x` ??

Comment: Claro, son los permisos. Debes leer acerca de los privilegios de archivos en linux. hay mucha información en la web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una buena pregunta. Incluso viendo la documentación del comando `ls` no queda claro que significa cada una de los columnas cuando se muestra en formato de lista usando `-l`.

- `drwxrwxr-x`: Estos son los permisos del archivo o carpeta. La `d` (directory) quiere decir que es una carpeta. Los `rwx` (read, write, execute) son los permisos de lectura, escritura y ejecución por cada uno de los conjuntos de permisos, es decir, el primer grupo de `rwx` son tus permisos como usuario sobre ese archivo, el segundo conjunto de `rwx` son los permisos del grupo al que perteneces como usuario, y el tercer conjunto de `rwx` son los permisos para los otros usuarios (aquellos que no están en tu grupo).
- `2`: Es el número de enlaces hacia este archivo o carpeta.
- `usertest`: El propietario de este archivo o carpeta.
- `usertest`: El grupo propietario de este archivo o carpeta.
- `4096`: El tamaño del archivo o carpeta (por defecto, en bytes: 4096 bytes).
- `jul 14 03:10`: Fecha de la última modificación del archivo o carpeta.
- `.`: Nombre del archivo o carpeta.

Ten en cuenta que el `-d` está listando la carpeta en la que te encuentras, y **no** su contenido. Es decir, si tienes una estructura como esta:

```
$ tree .
.
├── Caddyfile
└── Dockerfile

0 directories, 2 files
```

Que es una simple carpeta con dos archivos, entonces el comando `ls -ld` arrojará:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 cesar cesar 4096 Nov 28  2017 .
```

Mientras que el comando `ls -l` arrojará:

```
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar 364 Nov 28  2017 Caddyfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar  85 Nov 20  2017 Dockerfile
```

El `-l` simplemente usa el formato de lista larga.